# Criar fonte de dados ODBC Informix

Tags: banco-de-dados, odbc, informix

Problema: preciso registrar uma fonte de dados INFORMIX e não estou conseguindo.
Entro com os parâmetros, mas sempre ocorre erro. O que devo fazer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Tens de usar uma ligação **DRDA** à instância, e aparentemente os dados que estás a colocar não pertencem a uma.

Para poderes confirmar se existe uma ligação **DRDA** configurada podes executar a seguinte query:

```
SELECT
    dbsvrnm,
    hostname,
    svcname
FROM 
    sysmaster:syssqlhosts
WHERE 
    svrtype = 'dr';
```

Depois confirma se o `dbsvrnm` faz parte dos alias da instância, podes executar a seguinte query:

```
SELECT  cf_effective
FROM    sysmaster:syscfgtab 
WHERE   cf_name = 'DBSERVERALIASES';
```

Não existindo configurada tens de seguir os passos no [manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0207.htm?view=embed).